# What scope do I need to add Google auth 2.0 app?

Tags: php, google-api

I have issue with google auth app verification. i have app approved with following scope : email, profile, openid my app status is : Published 
now if i try to login using my own google account then i can successfully login through that app but if other user tried to login then they get app unverified message. please help me to solve this issue step by steps.

for more info check screenshot

[image]

Comment: Users outside your domain will get that warning until it's verified: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification

Comment: @lufc yes but my app sattus is already published though other users are still see the same error app not verified. anything i am missing ?

Comment: Read the link. Published != verified.